# Order by SQL line

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I go about creating an SQL line that puts each car from new to old (Years) but also keeps it in alphabetical order

For example it needs to do this

```
2018 Acura Model X
2018 Acura Model X
2017 Acura Model X
2017 Acura Model X
2018 Audi Model X
2017 Audi Model X
2018 BMW Model X
```

This is how its displaying

[MY View](http://rextester.com/DRY55288)

Comment: `select * from cars order by 2,1 desc`? read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: also, describe/publish your schema: people don't know how your db looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(name, 6), ' ', 1),   -- order ascending by model name
    LEFT(name, 4) DESC;                         -- order descending by model year
```

The call I make to `SUBSTRING_INDEX` extracts the second word from the model string.  This is assumed to be the model name.

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I tried that but this is how my comes up as [link] (http://rextester.com/DRY55288)

Comment: @youngkid7 Check [this demo](http://rextester.com/TXMGF50550).  Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to group the models together based on their newest date (and then the date for the model itself).

One method uses a subquery in the `order by`:

```
select c.*
from cars c
order by (select max(c2.year) from cars c2 where c2.model = c.model),
         c2.year desc;
```